# Using regex to isolate part of an embed code

Tags: regex

```
<script type="text/javascript"
 src="http://www.domain.com/script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function(
    123,
    "http://www.domain.com",
    "http://www.domain.com/videos/video.mp4",
    "http://www.domain.com/screengrabs/video.jpg"
  );
</script>
```

I need to isolate the video and the image in this embed code. I'm trying to use regex to accomplish this and I'm a little stuck.

I have--

```
(?:[^,]*\",){2}
```

Which matches--

```
 "http://www.domain.com", "http://www.domain.com/videos/video.mp4",
```

I'm having trouble getting it right. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\"([^\"]+(videos|screengrabs)[^\"]+)\"
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably I am too naive to belive that videos and images are always in same folder, 
but anyway

```
videos\/(.*?)".*screengrabs\/(.*?)"
```

video => $1, image $2